# How to safely close Database in ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

My Android application has a ViewModel that performs SQLite database operations using Kotlin coroutines.

If the Fragment of the ViewModel is closed while the DB operations are running, I want to make sure the DB is properly closed so there are no leaks.  In order to make sure I am not closing the DB while it is still being used, I first cancel the ViewModel job, and then call db.close().

However, if I close the fragment while the operation is still performing, I get a the following error:

`IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.`

How can I cancel the running jobs so I can safely close the database?

**ViewModel:**

```
class MyViewModel(
        private val db: DatabaseHelper,
) : ViewModel() {

    private var viewModelJob = Job()
    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

    init {
        initialize()
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelJob.cancel()
        db.close()
    }

    private fun initialize() {
        uiScope.launch {
            runQuery()
       }
    }

    private suspend fun runQuery() {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            //Perform long-running db operations
        }
    }
}
```

The stack trace points to the operations within the runQuery() function that are still running after the db has been closed.  I do not understand how that operation is still running when I close the db since I already called `viewModelJob.cancel()`

Comment: try `db.close()` before `super.onCleared()`

Comment: @MohammadSianaki Tried that, still get the same result